# Duda sobre la relacion de una tabla

Tags: mysql, tablas, relaciones

estoy haciendo un sistema de llantas y tengo una duda en la creacion de una tabla para el siguiente requerimiento:

- El sistema tendra un modulo de "rotacion de llantas", en la cual se ingresara 2 llantas: La llanta a rotar y la llanta por la que se va a rotar

Estuve pensando el modo de hacerlo e hice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit-01**

**Explicacion**

1. "llantas_informacion": Como su nombre indica sirva para poner la informacion de la llanta: "condicion, cocada y situacion"
2. "vehiculos_llantas": Aqui se pondran los vehiculos con la posicion de la llanta, la relacion seria "llantas_informacion->vehiculos_llantas", "uno-uno"
3. "reg_llantas_rota_mov": Significa "registro de llantas rotacion movimiento", quiere decir que aqui estaran todas las llantas que van a rotar, la llanta uno es la llanta a rotar y la llanta dos es la llanta por la que se va a rotar
4. "reg_llanta_rota": Significa "registro de llantas rotacion", sirve para guardar la informacion adicional de las llantas que se van a rotar, como la observacion y el vehiculo

Como ven, hay una tabla que dice "reg_llantas_rota_mov", en esta tabla guardo las 2 llantas que se obtienen de la tabla "llantas_informacion", mi pregunta es la siguiente:

- ¿La relacion hecha es correcta? (Ya que en una tabla estoy guardando 2 veces el `id` de la tabla "llantas informacion" donde guardo las 2 llantas que necesito)

Gracias a todos!

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos un poco más de contexto? Entiendo que esas llantas irán en un vehículo que será el que rote las llantas, ¿cómo es que no haces referencia a él en ninguna de tus tablas?

Comment: @DavidJP si tengo, actualizare la imagen para que veas la relacion completa

Comment: Definitivamente, creo que deberías simplificar tu esquema: si una llanta está rota puede ser un booleano de la propia llanta o incluso ser su propio estado. Las llantas rotas no pueden ser una entidad en sí mismas

Comment: @DavidJP A que se refiere por simplificar tu esquema", para hacer la actualizacion? Sobre lo otro, si una llanta va estar rota, entonces quedara registrado cuando su informacion

Comment: Me refiero a usar menos tablas, te he ampliado la respuesta. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios de esa misma respuesta y dejemos éstos para comentarios generales sobre tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo este modelo alternativo al tuyo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la relación `llevan` tendrás el registro de la rotación de todas las llantas que se han ido montando en cada vehículo.

Fíjate que, en tu propuesta, creas tablas para llantas rotas y vinculas directamente vehículos con llantas. Debes tener en cuenta que:

- Aunque se rompan, las llantas continúan siendo llantas. El hecho de que estén rotas es un simple atributo, como el color. Por lo tanto, no es necesario crear la entidad `reg_llantas_rota`.
- Por otra parte, la relación o tabla intermedia `reg_llantas_rota_mov`, con la que intentas llevar un registro de la rotación de las llantas, debería ir entre el vehículo y las llantas.
- Tampoco es necesario vincularla por dos campos a las llantas. Cada vez que montes una llanta en un vehículo generas un nuevo registro. Así, podrás almacenar todas las rotaciones de llantas que necesites, no únicamente dos.
- La creación de un módulo para gestionar la base de datos, no implica necesariamente la creación de nuevas tablas o entidades si lo puedes resolver añadiendo campos o atributos.

La implementación en MySQL sería algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE vehiculos(
  id_vehiculo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  placa varchar(15),
  km float
  );
CREATE TABLE llantas(
  id_llanta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  llanta varchar(15),
  estado varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE llevan(
  id_llevan int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_vehiculo int,
  id_llanta int,
  posicion varchar(2),
  fecha_montaje datetime,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_vehiculo) REFERENCES vehiculos(id_vehiculo),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_llanta) REFERENCES llantas(id_llanta)
  );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con estos datos de muestra:

```
INSERT INTO vehiculos (placa, km) VALUES
  ('1234 BHJ',23500),
  ('4567 DSK',50800);
INSERT INTO llantas (llanta,estado) VALUES
  ('B','Ok'),('A','Ok'),('C','Ok'),('D','Ok'),
  ('E','Ok'),('F','Ok'),('G','Ok'),('H','Ok');
INSERT INTO llevan (id_vehiculo, id_llanta, posicion, fecha_montaje) VALUES
  (1,1,'DI',NOW()),(1,2,'DD',NOW()),(1,3,'TI',NOW()),(1,4,'TD',NOW()),
  (2,5,'DI',NOW()),(2,6,'DD',NOW()),(2,7,'TI',NOW()),(2,8,'TD',NOW()),
  (1,1,'DD',NOW()+INTERVAL 36 HOUR),
  (1,2,'DI',NOW()+INTERVAL 36 HOUR);
```

Y esta consulta:

```
SELECT placa,llanta,posicion,fecha_montaje FROM llevan
  JOIN vehiculos USING(id_vehiculo)
  JOIN llantas USING(id_llanta)
  ORDER BY placa,posicion,fecha_montaje DESC;
```

Obtendrás el historial de llantas montadas en cada vehículo, de más reciente a más antigua:

```
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| placa    | llanta | posicion | fecha_montaje       |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 1234 BHJ | B      | DD       | 2021-02-21 20:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | A      | DD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | A      | DI       | 2021-02-21 20:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | B      | DI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | D      | TD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | C      | TI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | F      | DD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | E      | DI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | H      | TD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | G      | TI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

En cambio, si lo que buscas es saber en dónde ha estado montada cada llanta, puedes ordenar el resultado de la misma consulta de esta forma:

```
SELECT placa,llanta,posicion,fecha_montaje FROM llevan
  JOIN vehiculos USING(id_vehiculo)
  JOIN llantas USING(id_llanta)
  ORDER BY llanta,fecha_montaje DESC,placa,posicion;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| placa    | llanta | posicion | fecha_montaje       |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 1234 BHJ | A      | DI       | 2021-02-21 20:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | A      | DD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | B      | DD       | 2021-02-21 20:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | B      | DI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | C      | TI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 1234 BHJ | D      | TD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | E      | DI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | F      | DD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | G      | TI       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
| 4567 DSK | H      | TD       | 2021-02-20 08:28:24 |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

La posición de la llanta en el vehículo se codifica así:

```
DI - delantera izquierda
DD - delantera derecha
TI - trasera izquierda
TD - trasera derecha
```

Comment: Quiero disculparme con usted por no explicar el significado del nombre de mis tablas, editare mi pregunta y pondre el porque se creo cada tabla con su nombre

Comment: Por los demas puntos, entiendo, podria mostrarme un ejemplo de lo que dice "*deberia ir entre vehiculo y las llantas*", por lo que entiendo es que esa tabla intermedia debe estar relacionado con las 2 tablas, pero como seria el tipo de relacion "uno-uno, uno-muchos, etc"

Comment: Pues eso me lo tienes que decir tú: ¿Una llanta se puede colocar en varios vehículos? No simultáneamente, sino primero en uno y luego en otro. En cualquier caso, ya te ocuparás de la cardinalidad, antes debes asegurarte de cómo vas a guardar la información

Comment: Entiendo, en el modelo que propones, com seria la relacion? (Para implementarlo) Se puede unir "llevan con posicion y fecha_montaje", asi como "llantas y estado"? Podrias mostrarme? (Disculpa que suene como si estarias haciendo el trabajo, pero en verdad necesito ayuda en esto)

Comment: No te preocupes, mañana te lo implemento en MySQL para que lo veas

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta, ya me dices si te ayuda a dar con la solución

Comment: Interesante...en esta relacion se podria saber que llanta tenia antes y depues de la rotacion? Por ejemplo mi vehiculo tiene la llanta A en DD y llanta B en DI, hago la rotacion, ahora la llanta A estara en DI y la llanta B en DD, podria sacar el historial de esa relacion? Para decir: En este vehiculo se hizo la rotacion de esta llanta, esta era la posicion antigua y esta es la posicion nueva

Comment: Sí, claro. Mientras no borres los registros antiguos, podrás conservar el histórico de cada cambio. Te adapto la respuesta al ejemplo que propones.